# Get the Course start and expiry Date (timestart and timeend) via API Call (Moodle 2.7.2)

Tags: php, moodle

I am developing an new Moodle Development (LMS) with CI (codeIgnitor). The students are  registered in CI and using API (xmlrpc), the student details are enrolled in Moodle.

I did exploded the API list that offered in moodle, but i couldn't find the solution for my below requirement.

Via the API call, i wish to send the Candidate ID to moodle (it will be moodle user id only)  which need to get the list of courses enrolled by the candidate along with the start and expiry date (time start and the time end).

Is there any default core API call available?

Kindly share me the methods on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you a list of courses that a user is enrolled on

```
core_enrol_get_users_courses
```

Then use this to get the courses which will give you the start date

```
core_course_get_courses
```

The expiry date will be in the enrolment plugin but I couldn't find an api for that. So you'll probably need to write your own web service for that.

There's some guidelines on writing a web service here - https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Adding_a_web_service_to_a_plugin

Comment: Thanks much Mr. Russell for your time.. Will check your suggestion.